# AJAX POST request not working in safari when sending file with FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I have an API which uploads file on google cloud server and returns the url. I am using jquery ajax for API call. I am including file using FormData() object. It is working fine in chrome but when I am trying same in safari I get error which says cannot POST /my-own-site/link/index.html

Here is my code

```
  <form method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" id = "get-cloud-link">
     <input type="file" name = "filename" id = "image-input" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"/>
     <input type="text" name = "tag" value = "iwh" class = "hidden"/>
     <input type="text" name = "empID" value = "" class = "hidden"/>
     <input class = "theme-btn" type="submit" id = "get-cloud-link-btn" value = "Upload"/>
  </form>


  $("form#get-cloud-link").submit(function(e){

       var imageInput = $("#image-input");

     if(imageInput.val() == '' || imageInput.val() == null){
       alert('No image is selected, please select image first');
      } else {
     var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

     for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
       console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
     }

      $.ajax({
         url : ' link-to-api/external/upload',
         type : "POST",
         cache : false,
         contentType : false,
         processData : false,
         headers : {
            "appID" : "",
            "version" : "",
            "empID" : ""
         },
         data : formData,
         beforeSend : function(){
         $(".image-uploading-wrapper").show();
         //xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },
         complete : function(){$(".image-uploading-wrapper").hide();},
         success : function(data){

         createUploadImage(data.imageUrl);

         imageInput.val("");

      },
         error : function(e){console.log(e)}
      });
    }
        e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: it seems it is not support with append with filename https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Is there any other way I can attach image as data object in jquery ajax?

Comment: have a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/jquery-form/form)

Comment: Can you share error from console?

Comment: Have you tried to append the file instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object